# gradle upgrade from 4 to gradle 6.0 - Replacing an existing task that may have already been used by other plugins is not supported

Tags: gradle, upgrade

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.jacobono.wsdl']
> Could not create task ':party-request-v2-ws:war'.
> > Replacing an existing task that may have already been used by other plugins is not supported.  Use a different name for this task ('war').

I get the above error for a subproject. May I please have some suggestions as to how to deal with these kind of issues. do I need to replace com.github.jacobono.wsdl plugin?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538382/368220) answer, Gradle prior to 5.1.0 supported replacing tasks. Gradle 5 deprecated this feature and Gradle 6 removed it. I'm afraid you cannot use the com.github.jacobono.wsdl plugin with Gradle 6.